# How to update only the cloudinary Image of a User model?

Tags: cloudinary, keystonejs

There is not code which demonstrate the update of clodinary Image.
The code I have written below do update the Image but then I can not immediately use the FIll, or limit method of cloudinary Image.

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.files.icon.path, function(img, err) { 
    console.log(img) 
    if(err){
        res.send(err);
    }else{
        req.user.update({$set: {icon: img}}, function (err, count) {
            res.send(img.fill(300,300));// this line says fill not defined.
           //res.send(_img.fill(300,300));// this also fails
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the `img` that's returned isn't the actual image, it's a result JSON of the image's details. 
Also, please have a look at [the documentation](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_image_manipulation) to see how transformations are generated. Specifically, to apply a 300x300 fill crop, you need to add `c_fill,h_300,w_300` to the URL, which could be achieved with something similar to:

```
cloudinary.image(img.public_id, { format: "jpg", width: 100, height: 150, crop: "fill" })
```

Comment: Thanks the most important thing I learned from your response is that I can use img.public_id as parameter, that was not documented I guess.   I used this function cloudinary.url(img.public_id, { format: "jpg", width: 100, height: 150, crop: "fill" })  instead of what u suggested.

Comment: You're right. `cloudinary.url` would make more sense in this case. Glad I could help.